# How can I show a message before users are logged in?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have a site. In the header there is a log in button. I want to show a message like "New here? Log in now" . But once the user is logged in, I want to hide the message.

How can I do that?

Here is the HTML code for the div

```
<div class="bfr_login_msg">
<p>New here? Log in now </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Use PHP's `$_SESSION`, but what did you try so far?

Comment: How are you logging the users in?

Comment: i am using wordpress for my site. and i have an login page that has a login field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.logged-in .bfr_login_msg {
display:none;
}
```

All you need to do is use that in your CSS to hide the message for logged-in users. WordPress has a "logged-in" body class.

Alternatively, you could wrap that in your template and use PHP.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo '<a href="login-page">New here? Log in now</a>'; 
}
?>
```